# Evaluating an iOS crash report (app built with phonegapbuild so can't symbolicate in xcode)

Tags: ios, crash, report, phonegap-build

Below is the crash report from Apple.

Here is a web version of the app: http://www.web4uonline.com/yalecc/26/main.html

I built the app with phonegap build so I don't think I can have XCode evaluate the crash report any further than what is below.

```
Incident Identifier: 75BAD699-7113-4C6E-A973-1FC0C5A7BE89
CrashReporter Key:   f007efd015d54832edfad6b6f673eb18289bfde9
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:         STMYale [139]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/1218F21C-4BE1-4F94-9344-D6D03351937C/STMYale.app/STMYale
Identifier:      STMYale
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)

Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-08-20 17:30:25.491 -0700

OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)

Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Crashed Thread:  0



Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x32e1f29e 0x3acc397a 0x32d7055a 0x32da70ce 0xf0afe 0xf33c8 0xf5f0e 0x32e229c0 0x32d79fe6 0x32d79b3e 0x3968464e 0x32e21616 0x32d78f64 0x32e229c0 0x32d79fe6 0x38dafcee 0x38decd08 0x32df467e 0x32df3ee4 0x32df2cb2 0x32d65eb8 0x32d65d44 0x3691a2e6 0x34c7b2fc 0xf8a26 0xf8a00)



Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b1c1350 __pthread_kill + 8

1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b13811e pthread_kill + 54

2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b17496e abort + 90

3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3a712d4a abort_message + 70

4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3a70fff4 default_terminate() + 20

5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3acc3a74 _objc_terminate() + 144

6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3a710078 safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 76

7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3a710110 std::terminate() + 16

8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3a711594 __cxa_rethrow + 84

9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3acc39cc objc_exception_rethrow + 8

10  CoreFoundation                  0x32d65f1c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452

11  CoreFoundation                  0x32d65d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100

12  GraphicsServices                0x3691a2e6 GSEventRunModal + 70

13  UIKit                           0x34c7b2fc UIApplicationMain + 1116

14  STMYale                         0x000f8a26 main + 30

15  STMYale                         0x000f8a00 start + 36

Thread 1:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b1c1d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8

1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b10fcf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14

2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b10fa12 _pthread_wqthread + 362

3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b10f8a0 start_wqthread + 4


ommitted threads because stack overlow had 30,000 character limit.


Thread 13:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b1c1d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8

1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b10fcf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14

2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b10fa12 _pthread_wqthread + 362

3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b10f8a0 start_wqthread + 4


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):

r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x3ccb7534

r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3ccb7b88      r6: 0x1f113684      r7: 0x2fd48a34

r8: 0x1f113660    r9: 0x00000300     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x3ccb7608

ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fd48a28      lr: 0x3b138123      pc: 0x3b1c1350

cpsr: 0x00000010


Binary Images:

</string>
    <key>displayName</key>
    <string>STMYale</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>STMYale</string>
    <key>os_version</key>
    <string>iPhone OS 6.1.3 (10B329)</string>
    <key>system_ID</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>version</key>
    <string>??? (???)</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Note from Apple: Your app crashes intermittently.

This occurred when your app was used: 

- Offline
- On Wi-Fi 
- On cellular network

Comment: It looks like the crash is already symbolicated. Thread 0 crashed and the first two frames have 'start' and 'main' which are symbols. Its just that there is nothing else to symbolicate.

Comment: You could try to symbolicate it manually with atos but the 'Binary Images' section is missing which would have the load address required to get that done.

Answer (score 0):

Your crashlog is broken.

The

> Binary Images:

section is completely missing, without that no load address (and other useful info) can be found by the symbolizer, it will not be able to symbolize the log